# Where can I download full example java project that uses stringtemplate?

Tags: templates, template-engine, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+4+Wiki+Home,  http://www.stringtemplate.org/

I looked on the wiki and I may be missing the forest through all the trees, but I need to see a fully working java project not a bunch of snips.  Ideally several full projects (github?) that contain:

- biz logic.
- header.htm, body.htm, and footer.htm.
- Multiple body pages so you can see how they interact with the biz logic.

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After exhaustive searching I can only conclude that there are no full/example projects for StringTemplate.

I have kept coming back to look at StringTemplate hoping to give it a go, but it really is difficult to get started, especially when most of the doucmentation has the following:

```
"These examples work with StringTemplate 3"
```

And its not clear how to get it working with StringTemplate 4

Comment: agreed. I've given up too on it. Switched to Velocity, which is old now but the learning curve is zero really.